# How to retain the values in form after validation error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a validation in my form for email. If the user is already registered, it shows the alert and resets the form with null value. I need the alert message as well as data should retain in the form.
Thanks in advance.
https://plnkr.co/edit/WhdRmJmLs69yaf6Q2uYI?p=preview

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" ng-disabled="!edit" name="firstName" ng-model="user.firstName" ng-required="true">
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="userForm.myName.$touched && userForm.myName.$invalid">Please enter a First Name</span>
                </div>

                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!edit" name="email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true">
                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="userForm.email.$touched && userForm.email.$invalid">Please enter valid email ID</span>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click='edit=!edit'id="Edit" ng-show="!edit" class="btn btn-default" >Edit</button>
            <button ng-show="edit" id="save" type="submit" ng-click='addOrModifyUser(user)' class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Save
            </button>
            <a ng-if="user.accountId" ui-sref="account.locations.contacts({accountId: user.accountId})">
                <button type="type" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </a>
            </div>
```

I?p=preview

Comment: save it in another variable before $http call to verify the uniqueness.

Comment: Your plunk is not a working demo which demonstrates the problem you have. The HTML page doesn't even include Angular JS files.

Comment: Are you checking the uniqueness of Email? then go with directive way. right now you are using `$state.reload()` and `$location.path()` which will reload the complete page, so you will lose all the data obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what your problem is here but this is how I would have solved a custom email validation check in angular 1.x.

**Html:**

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" ng-model="formModel.email" />
    <span ng-show="formModel.$submitted && formModel.teamName.$error.exists">Email already exists</span>
</form>
```

**Js:** (in your angular controller) where "EmailService" would be your http service of choice that checks if email exists against your backend:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, EmailService) {


    $scope.submit = function() {

        $scope.formModel.email.$setValidity("exists", true);
        EmailService.emailExist($scope.formModel.email,  { // check if email exists
            success: function(exists) {

                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.formModel.email.$setValidity("exists", !exists); // set validation flag
                });

                if($scope.formModel.$valid) {
                    // submit if valid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!